# How to change regression line type per group using facet_wrap() in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression, facet-wrap

If I have a data like below, I made a linear regression graph per location.

```
location=rep(c("A","B","C"),each=5)
nitrogen=rep(c(0,10,20,30,40), time=3)
yield=c(15,20,25,29,38,10,20,40,50,55,15,17,16,17,20)
dataA=data.frame(location, nitrogen, yield)

ggplot(data=dataA, aes(x=nitrogen, y=yield))+
   stat_smooth(method='lm', linetype=1, se=FALSE, formula=y~x, linewidth=0.5) +
   geom_point(color="black", size=4) +
   scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,40,10), limits = c(0,40)) +
   scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,60,10), limits = c(0,60)) +
   labs(x="N rate", y="Grain Yield") +
   facet_wrap(~location) +
   theme_grey(base_size=20, base_family="serif")+
   theme(axis.line=element_line(linewidth=0.5, colour="black"))+
   windows(width=8, height=7)
```

and the graph looks like below.

Now in location C, it does not show the linearity. So I want to not show the regression line (or provide different color or dotted line, etc.,) in only location C.

Could you let me know how to change regression line type per group?

Always many thanks!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do what you want by multiple `stat_smooth()` with different data.
For instance, different color and linetype in location C.

You can use three `stat_smooth()`s, if you want to change style of regression line by each group (i.e. A,B,C).

```r
library(ggplot2)

location=rep(c("A","B","C"),each=5)
nitrogen=rep(c(0,10,20,30,40), time=3)
yield=c(15,20,25,29,38,10,20,40,50,55,15,17,16,17,20)
dataA=data.frame(location, nitrogen, yield)
ggplot(data=dataA, aes(x=nitrogen, y=yield))+
  geom_point(color="black", size=4) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,40,10), limits = c(0,40)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,60,10), limits = c(0,60)) +
  labs(x="N rate", y="Grain Yield") +
  facet_wrap(~location) +
  stat_smooth(data=dataA[dataA$location!="C",], method="lm", se=F)+
  stat_smooth(data=dataA[dataA$location=="C",], method="lm", se=F, lty=2, color="red",
              formula = y ~poly(x,2)) +
  theme_grey(base_size=20, base_family="serif")+
  theme(axis.line=element_line(linewidth=0.5, colour="black"))
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>